# Using UPDATE FROM to mass-set a field

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-update

I have the following query that I've used to pull out a vehicle ID, it's registration, a driver id and the driver's name.  The `_core_people` table you see referenced in this query also a field I wish to set to the vehicle's plate.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT fv._plate, cp._people_name
FROM
_fleet_vehicle fv,
_fleet_vehicle_status fvs,
_core_people cp,
_fleet_allocation fa
WHERE 
cp._id_hierarchy = fv._id_hierarchy
AND fv._id_status = fvs._id
AND fvs._status_live = 1
AND fa._id_person = cp._id
AND fa._id_vehicle = fv._id
AND fa._alloc_end_date IS NULL
ORDER BY cp._people_name ASC
```

Now, I want to write an `UPDATE...FROM` clause that utilises this to set `_core_people._plate` (not shown here) to the plate field of their vehicle.

However, I'm not sure how to go about structuring the `UPDATE...FROM` clause.

Also, some drivers have 2 cars.  Will it still work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE  _core_people
SET     _plate = fv._plate
FROM    _fleet_vehicle fv,
        _fleet_vehicle_status fvs,
        _core_people cp,
        _fleet_allocation fa
WHERE   cp._id_hierarchy = fv._id_hierarchy
        AND fv._id_status = fvs._id
        AND fvs._status_live = 1
        AND fa._id_person = cp._id
        AND fa._id_vehicle = fv._id
        AND fa._alloc_end_date IS NULL
```

If there are more than 1 record for `_core_people` matching the condition, `_core_people` will be updated to only one of them (it is not possible to tell which one exactly).

Comment: Huh, pretty simple when you look at it.  That worked a charm, thank-you very much for your prompt response.